Improving ventilation in the basement unit
I have a small basement unit which I use as a small woodworking workshop (see drawing). The unit has door only and it connected to the corridor with a window at the end.
Of course, every time I am in the unit, I open both door and window. The fresh air comes from the street (shaft) and goes through the window and door to my workshop.
I have 700 to 800 ppm of CO2 (measured) and about 45% humidity. This is fine but the air in the basement is just stale and I need better ventilation.
Any ideas what would be helpful here? I can not put anything on the window, only in my unit.
I was thinking about ceiling fan which could boost the flow of air and hopefully bring more fresh air into the workshop.
Thanks.


Dehumidifier would be the obvious starting step.

Why? The humidity is not a problem at all, the basement is not humid (45% humidity).

In my experience, "stale basement" usually means excessively humid, and 45% is not low humidity. Unless you are producing fumes you need to extract, in which case the answer is powered ventilation, ideally  HRV.

@keshlam 45% is a normal humidity level.  But even with normal RH the air is stale, simply because there's no ventilation (or even circulation).  OP, you would need to provide a way to circulate air.  Without another opening somewhere else, it's difficult.  How do you (and neighbor) access this space?

In the back there is a door to staircase. Of course, I could open the door and get some ventilation but it is not going through my unit but only though the corridor. And of course I do produce noice in my workshop so opening the door to the staircase and exposing neighbours to this noice is not very good.
